# How to ProjectTo from a base type to a type only known at runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

We are using Entity Framework Core, with a set of Entities that all share a base class.

```
public class EntityBase { ... }

public class FirstEntityChild : EntityBase { ... }
public class SecondEntityChild : EntityBase { ... }
```

We use this so we can query for either a `FirstEntityChild` or `SecondEntityChild` without needing to know which one at compile time.

To provide the data to our view, we have view models.

```
public class FirstEntityChildViewModel { ... }
public class SecondEntityChildViewModel { ... }
```

We're hoping to use AutoMapper's `ProjectTo` to map the query results from our database entity to a view model. We have mapping profiles set up from `FirstEntityChild` to `FirstEntityChildViewModel` and from `SecondEntityChild` to `SecondEntityChildViewModel`. We have no maps from `EntityBase`.

We're currently attempting to accomplish this through type inference with an extension method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> query,
    TSource sourceTypeInstance,
    TDestination destinationTypeInstance,
    IConfigurationProvider configuration)
{
    return query.ProjectTo<TDestination>(configuration);
}
```

And we're using that as follows, given that `sourceType` is either `FirstEntityChild` or `SecondEntityChild`, and targetType is either `FirstEntityChildViewModel` or `SecondEntityChildViewModel`, and both are known only at runtime:

```
var sourceInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(sourceType);
var targetInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);

var results = await query
    .ProjectTo(sourceInstance, targetInstance, mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The issue we're facing happens inside our `ProjectTo` extension. When I debug and stop on that line, `sourceTypeInstance` and `destinationTypeInstance` appear in the debugger to be `FirstEntityChild` and `FirstEntityChildViewModel` respectively. But when the line executes, **AutoMapper attempts to map from `EntityBase` to `object`,** which we don't have a mapping profile for (and which I don't think would even be possible):

*InvalidOperationException: Missing map from EntityBase to System.Object. Create using Mapper.CreateMap.*

Is it possible to indicate the actual, derived type AutoMapper should be using? Or are we just bumping up against the limitations of generics at this point?

Comment: Do you have maps from `FirstEntityChild` to `FirstEntityChildViewModel`? or do you only have maps from `EntityBase` to something?

Comment: We do have maps from `FirstEntityChild` to `FirstEntityChildViewModel` and `SecondEntityChild` to `SecondEntityChildViewModel`. No maps from `EntityBase` to anything else. Thank you for pointing this out, I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I mean there must be more to this, why are you creating instance through Activator and then immediately mapping it? Even if you did that, wouldn't mapping `default(TSource)` to `default(TDestination` would be better? Why is `sourceInstance` even needed here since you intend source to come from EF?

Comment: I will make a wild bet that your `mapper.ConfigurationProvider` maybe doesn't hold the config for your maps.

Comment: We use Activator because we start with only knowing the types we're coming from and mapping to at runtime, so we're using type inference to allow using ProjectTo. I'm certain our mapping profiles are correct because using `Map` on an enumerated list of our entities works just fine. Besides, the error message we get indicates that AutoMapper isn't using our mapping profiles, as it is mapping from and to the wrong types.

Comment: but in here `return query.ProjectTo<TDestination>(configuration);` you are not using either `sourceTypeInstance` neither `destinationTypeInstance` and this seems to be the only line in that function, which makes those params redundant.

Comment: Are you familiar with type inference? Those parameters allow us to let the types be inferred at runtime. Type arguments can not be variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197996/discussion-between-jimmy-and-vidmantas-blazevicius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reflection to create a generic method out of ProjectTo and your destination type and then invoke that method to get the results of ProjectTo. For instance:

```
public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> query,
    TSource sourceTypeInstance,
    TDestination destinationTypeInstance,
    IConfigurationProvider configuration)
{
    var projectToMethod = typeof(AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions)
            .GetMethod("ProjectTo", new Type[]
            {
                typeof(IQueryable),
                typeof(IConfigurationProvider),
                typeof(IDictionary<string, object>),
                typeof(string[])
            })
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TDestination));
    return projectToMethod.Invoke(query, new object[] { query, configuration, new Dictionary<string, object>(), new string[] { } });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this helps at all.  How can you even call the extension method if you don't know the TSource and TDestination types until runtime?